# JSF Validator for edit page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have problem which I cannot solve. I have a JSF edit page which displays data generated from Java Object. The page displays values into input forms as it should be. And now I get this problem. For example I have a input value with original value `12`. when I insert value 22 the validator of the input form checks and returns message `22 is not a unique value`.

Then I enter again the value 12 and I get again the message `12 is not a unique value` How I can tell to this validator that this value `12` is acceptable value and it should accept it even if it's repeated into the DB because this is a original value taken from the Java Object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add validation method to your backing bean and validate against the current value in model . Current model value should be the last validated value bound in the backing bean.

or if its a separate validator then its already answered above.